# Sed wildcard search tick (') and replace

Tags: bash, sed

I can't seem to remember how to replace a tick in a document using the wildcard function.

Here is data.txt:

```
 +40 46'N + 014 15'E
 +21 17'N -157  52'W
```

I want to replace everything after the ' with S. The sed command gives me errors when I try:

```
 sed 's/'.*/S/g' data.txt > new.txt
```

It seems that searching for ticks and replacing them is an issue with sed? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping it:

```
sed 's/'\''.*/S/g' data.txt > new.txt
```

Or use double quotes

```
sed "s/'.*/S/g" data.txt > new.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

try this line:

```
sed "s/'.*/S/" file
```

or

```
sed 's/\x27.*/S/' file
```

to avoid to escape single quote.

P.S. You don't need the `g` flag.

Comment: what does x27 do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes quoting `'` is not enough. You should place it between `[]`.

```
sed "s/['].*/S/" data.txt
```

Example output:

```
 +40 46S
 +21 17S
```

If you actually mean *only* everything after, you can do this:

```
sed "s/^\([^']*[']\).*/\1S/" data.txt
```

Example output:

```
 +40 46'S
 +21 17'S
```

If you only mean the letters next to every instance:

```
sed "s/\([']\)[^[:space:]]\+/\1S/g" data.txt
```

Output:

```
 +40 46'S + 014 15'S
 +21 17'S -157  52'S
```